# How to automatically create/schedule a lambda function through amplify.yml (without the CLI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amazon-cloudwatch

Here is a summary of the context for the question:

- Using a NextJS application;
- Trying to run builds on AWS amplify;
- Application depends on a lambda function periodically calling some URLs;
- We have AWS studio and PR previews enabled;

If we create and schedule the lambda functions manually, we can get things to work, but the ideal scenario would be that the functions get automatically created and schedule based on the directives on the amplify.yml file (which is placed at the root of the project).

We tried using the following amplify.yml file:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: client/
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - (some other preparation commands)
            
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: .next
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    backend:
      functions:
        cronJob${env:ENV_NAME}:
          service: Lambda
          handler: lambda-functions/cronjob.handler
          runtime: nodejs14.x
          environment:
            (some envs for the lambda)
          events:
            - cloudwatchEvent:
                event:
                  source:
                    - "aws.events"
                  detail:
                    eventName:
                      - ${env:ENV_NAME}Event
                parameters:
                  schedule: "cron(0/1 * * * ? *)"  # Trigger every minute
```

Trying to run the build on AWS amplify, it goes past the backend stage with the following error:
"No backend environment association found, continuing..."

Probably there is something wrong with the syntax on the "backend" section (or maybe even with the configuration on the AWS amplify panel), but we could not find any documentation detailing exactly this part (for how exactly a lambda function can be created/scheduled via directives on the amplify.yml).

Could also be that this is not possible, and we have to go, for example, the way of integrating amplify CLI on the project, and calling the commands to setup a lambda function on a preparation phase of the build.

Either way, some clarification would be appreciated.